# What can we do to encourage people to participate here in meta?

Tags: discussion

The title says it all. Do you not participate because you have nothing to say? Do you simply not know about meta? (In which case we'll see no answers to this meta question.) Are you simply not interested in participating?

Comment: The people who do not participate in Meta will not see this post.

Comment: Up-vote it: When the score is 3 or higher, the question appears in the Community Bulletin.

Answer (score 2):

If everything is going well, people do not need to be visiting meta.

Participating in meta is not a goal in and of itself.

Comment: Well, [for certain values of meta. . .](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: @JonathanGarber what do you mean?

Comment: While this does answer somewhat, I think that the problem the OP asks here is how to encourage people participate in meta to make sure that everything goes well. There are problems, and they don't help. That's the problem.

Answer (score -3):

We don't know about Meta. Otherwise we think it is not important.